# I have total 3 test cases 2 test case in parent class and 1 in child class, when I am running script testcases from first class runs two time

Tags: java, xml, selenium-webdriver, testng, testcase

I have one package Two classes and total 3 test cases two test cases in parent class and one in child class but when I am running script testcases from first classes runs two time. at the starting and once again after  when test runs from second class. I am initiating the application in parent class only

> Parent Class

```
package sanityTest;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
//import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class AdminLogin {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    static Alert alert;
    static String alertmessage = "MenuItem created successfully.";
    static String alertmessage1 = "Menuitem name should be minimum 1 and maximum 150 character.";
    static String alertmessage2 = "Please enter alphanumeric menuitem name with min 1 and max 150 of length.";
    static String alertmessage3 = "Are you sure you want to create recipe?";
    static String alertmessage4 = "Menu item already exists";
    static WebDriverWait wait;



    @Test (priority =1)
    public  void  adminLogin() throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Downloads\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get("App url");

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/p/a[1]/b/span")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"userName\"]")).sendKeys("admin");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"pass\"]")).sendKeys("admin@1234");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/form/button[1]")).click();

        String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();

        if ("App url"))
        {
        System.out.println("Admin Logged in successfullly");
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Login Unsuccessfull");  
        }

        //Selects Partner from Dashboard
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"bootstrap-data-table\"]/tbody/tr[7]/td[4]/center/button")).click();
        System.out.println("Partner Selected from Dashboard");
    }


    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    @Test (priority = 2)
    public static void createMenuItem()throws Exception
    {

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"main-menu\"]/ul/li[4]/a")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"main-menu\"]/ul/li[4]/ul/li[2]/a")).click();

        String url1 = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        if (url1.equals("App Url"))
        {
        System.out.println("Create Menuitem form opened successfullly");
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Create Menuitem form not opened");  
        }




        File file = new File("C:/Users/Desktop/MenuNames.xls");
        Workbook w = Workbook.getWorkbook(file);
        Sheet menulist = w.getSheet("Sheet1");
        int rows = menulist.getRows();
        int columns = menulist.getColumns();
        System.out.println(rows);
        System.out.println(columns);


        String menlistInput [] [] =  new String [rows] [columns];
        for (int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
             for (int j=0; j<columns; j++){

            Cell c = menulist.getCell(j, i);
            menlistInput [i][j] =c.getContents();
            System.out.println(menlistInput [i][j]);
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("['@#_()*]*");

              String str = menlistInput [i][j];
              Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);


        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"mitems\"]")).sendKeys(menlistInput [i][j]);



                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"menu\"]")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"menu\"]/option[3]")).click();


        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"checkbox\"]")).click();



        if (menlistInput [i][j].isEmpty() || matcher.matches() ) {

        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        String alertText = alert.getText();
        if(alertText.equals(alertmessage1) || alertText.equals(alertmessage2))
        {
            System.out.println("MenuItem Name is blank or contains special characters");
            System.out.println(alertText);
            alert.accept();

            break;
        }
        }





        Alert alert = null;
        try {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5 /*timeout in seconds*/);
            alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
        }catch(Exception exp8) { 

        }

        if(alert == null) {
            System.out.println("alert was not present");
            Thread.sleep(3000);
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/button[2]")).click();

        }
        else {
            String Recipemessage = alert.getText();
            System.out.println(Recipemessage);

            if (Recipemessage.equals(alertmessage2) || Recipemessage.equals(alertmessage4)) {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                alert.accept();
                break;
            }
        }


        Thread.sleep(3000);
        Set<String>allowWindow= driver.getWindowHandles();

        ArrayList<String>tabs=new ArrayList <> (allowWindow);

        try {
        driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
        driver.close();
        driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(0));
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {

        }




        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"fetch_data_div\"]/div[2]/center/button"));



        Thread.sleep(2000);

        //Enter Description
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"desc\"]")).sendKeys("Mastaniiii");

        //Upload Image      
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"menu_img\"]")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\RSL\\Desktop\\test.jpg");;

        //Click On Submit
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);


    boolean invisible = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("pageloaddiv")));

      if(invisible)
      {
          driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"menuitem_form\"]/div[11]/button[1]")).click();
      }


      Thread.sleep(3000);

      alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
     // System.out.println(alert.getText());

      if(alert.getText().equals(alertmessage) || alert.getText().equals(alertmessage2))
      {
       System.out.println(alert.getText());
       Thread.sleep(3000);
     // driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"menuitem_form\"]/div[11]/button[1]")).click();
       alert.accept();//Click on OK button
      break;
      }
     else
      {
       System.out.println("Menuitem Not created");

     }
      Thread.sleep(3000);
     // driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"menuitem_form\"]/div[11]/button[1]")).click();
       alert.accept();//Click on OK button

    }
        }
    }
    }
```

> Child class

```
package sanityTest;
import sanityTest.AdminLogin;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class EditMenuItem extends AdminLogin {



  @Test //(priority = 1)
  public void editMenu() throws InterruptedException {

      Thread.sleep(2000);

      //Click On MENU
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"main-menu\"]/ul/li[4]/a")).click();
      System.out.print("click on MENU");

      //Select Display Menu Item
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"main-menu\"]/ul/li[4]/ul/li[4]/a")).click();
      System.out.println("Menu Item List opened");

      //driver.close();
  }
```

> xml Class

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Menu">
  <test name="sanityTest">
    <classes>
      <class name="sanityTest.AdminLogin"/>
     <class name="sanityTest.EditMenuItem"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Comment: you show some code that will never comply, without any context about what it is supposed to test. what exactly are we trying here? can you show your actual code? also: if ChildClass actually extends ParentClass, then it also inherits the methods (tests) therein.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. In your example ChildClass is not extending ParentClass but I suppose it is the case. When a class is extending another one it is inheriting all its methods. In this specific case it will inherit all the @Test annotated method. Once you execute your suite both classes will be executed and in fact your child class contains 3 tests, two of which will be the exact duplicate of the ones in parent class.

Comment: @Stultuske I have updated my post with realtime code

Comment: @SergioArrighi Is there any solution?

Comment: EditMenuItem extends AdminLogi this means that when you execute the tests in EditMenuItem, you will also execute those from AdminLogin. It's basic inheritance.

Comment: @Tester as it is right now you could execute only the EditMenuItem in your suite, but I've never seen JUnit classes extending one another. Maybe is worth asking why you needed to do so and maybe you could refactor your code to delegate common code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per JAVA inheritance concept, if we extend any class to its child, first parent will be executed and then child. Because of this concept only, we are able to achieve Method Overriding in Java (Overriding parent method with the child method).
Coming to your case, you have written 'AdminLogin' as parent class and  'EditMenuItem' as a child class by extending AdminLogin class. Hence, whenever you try to execute child class (EditMenuItem), first parent class (AdminLogin ) will be executed and then child class.

Next is pom.xml, where you are calling parent class first and then child class.
As per given sequence, Parent class will be executed first and then child class. When selenium tried to execute child, it should execute parent too (as per inheritance concept). That's the reason parent class is running twice in your case.

To fix this issue, do not extend AdminLogin class to your child class and keep pom.xml as it is. By this way, First AdminLogin will be executed and then the child class which you mentioned as a second class in hierarchy in pom.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I didn't take deep look into your tests, and I don't see the real reason why you need inheriting. BUT you could try marking the parent class as ABSTRACT. This way tests will only be executed in the child class.

I have used this technique in c# and Nunit, but I would guess it works similar way in Java.